# Check quantity of item and append correct price either Sales price or Regular price based on sales variable

Tags: javascript, frontend, logic, javascript-objects, modulo

The task is to build an accurate price calculator which accounts for a sales price based on quantity. I've built a gross price calculator using compiledCart.reduce() method, (below) however I can't figure out how to add the sales functionality.

If the user buys 1 Candy, the price is $3.97, if the user buys 2, the price is $5.00. **If the user buys 3, then first two are $5.00 and the 3rd is $3.97. Same thing if the user buys 5. The first 4 are $10 and the 5th one is $3.97**

My compiledCart variable looks like this:

```
    [ 
     0: {item: "candy", quantity: 3, price: 3.97, salesPrice: 5.00}, 
     1: {item: "bread", quantity: 1, price: 2.17} 
    ]
```

This is what I'm doing to get the gross:

```
    const gross = compiledCart.reduce( ( sum, { price, quantity } ) => sum + (price * quantity) , 0)
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to factor in the sales price variable.

I tried using the modulous % operator like this:

```
    quantity % 2
```

But that only returns a 1 or 0 based on if there is a reminder. So 2 candies in the cart will return a 0 while 1 candy will return a 1 since 1 / 2 = 1. But I'm not sure how I can use that for my cause?

Comment: what is the expected total value of given compileCart ?

Comment: the modulus operator is a good start. It sure looks like if the mod is 0, you have numCandies * 2.5 and otherwise you have (numCandies -1)*2.50 + 3.97.

Comment: @azad the total of the compiled cart as it exists right now should be $11.14. (2 candies @ 5 dollars for both 1 candy @ 3.97 and 1 bread @ 2.17).

Comment: @jeremykahan I’m confused where are you are getting 2.50 from.

Comment: @n-dev-101I modified my answer please check it

Comment: 2 is 5, 4 is 10, ..., so when it's even, they are costing 2.50 each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const gross = cart.reduce((sum, {price, quantity, salesPrice = 0}) => {
    let total = 0;
    if (quantity >= 2) {
        const saleQuantity = 2 * Math.floor(quantity / 2);
        console.log({saleQuantity, remainderQuantity: quantity - saleQuantity});
        total = ((saleQuantity / 2) * salesPrice) + (price * (quantity - saleQuantity));
    } else {
        total = (price * quantity);
    }
    return sum + total;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the quantity is greater than 2 then:

divide the quantity by 2 and multiply by `salesPrice`

```js
var compiledCart = [ 
     {item: "candy", quantity: 3, price: 3.97, salesPrice: 5.00}, 
     {item: "bread", quantity: 1, price: 2.17} 
    ];

var sum = compiledCart.reduce((sum, { quantity, price, salesPrice = 0 }) => {

        let tot = 0;
        if (quantity > 1)
            tot = Math.trunc(quantity / 2) * (salesPrice || price);
        
        if (quantity % 2 == 1)
          tot += price;

        return sum + tot;
    }, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: this does not work. Because if you change the candy quantity to 4, the total should be $12.17 (4 candies at $5 per two = $10 + 1 bread at $2.17 = $12.17). Any ideas?

Comment: @n-dev-101 I updated the answer please check